# Android How To change Tab Icons on tab click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Android:

I am new to android I want to change tab icons on tab click. i have followed may tutorials that guide how to change tab icons via selecter xml file like

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/

but in my cause why all these not work  it change only first tab icons selected to unselected and unselected to selected  but not work for all others  where is the problem in my code please help me plz plz plz

my code is as follow

my drawable icons setting file is as follow  with names as

becel_setting.xml under drawable folder

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- When selected, -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_promenera_selected"
          android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_pressed="false" />

    <!-- When not selected, -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_promenera"
         />

    <!-- When selected, -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_varaframsteg_selected"
          android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_pressed="false" />
    <!-- When not selected, -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_varaframsteg"
         />

    <!-- When selected,  -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_minapromenader_selected"
          android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_pressed="false" />
    <!-- When not selected,-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_minapromenader"
         />

    <!-- When selected,  -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_information_selected"
          android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_pressed="false" />
    <!-- When not selected, -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_information"
         />

</selector>
```

and my tab host host class is as follow

```
public class BECEL extends TabActivity{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        try{
            setMenuTabs();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            String message = ex.getMessage();
        }
    }

    private void setMenuTabs() {
        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost

        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        /*******************************************/

        intent = new Intent(this, BecelFacebookConnection.class);

        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("").setIndicator("",
        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.becel_setting)).setContent(intent);  /**** xml file name becel_setting ******/
        tabHost.addTab(spec);        



        intent = new Intent(this, OurProgress.class);
        Drawable mySelector = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_varaframsteg);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("").setIndicator("",mySelector).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);



        intent = new Intent(this, MyWalks.class);

        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("").setIndicator("",
        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_minapromenader)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);



        intent = new Intent(this, WalkInformations.class);

        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("").setIndicator("",
        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_information)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    }
}
```

Please help me where is problem in my code

Answer (score 1):

you need to provide a unique string value for your each **newTabSpec("")**. for example *tab1*, *tab2*, *tab3* and *tab4* in the following example:

```
public class BECEL extends TabActivity{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        try{
            setMenuTabs();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            String message = ex.getMessage();
        }
    }

    private void setMenuTabs() {
        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost

        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        /*******************************************/

        intent = new Intent(this, BecelFacebookConnection.class);

        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("tab1",
        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.becel_setting)).setContent(intent);  /**** xml file name becel_setting ******/
        tabHost.addTab(spec);        



        intent = new Intent(this, OurProgress.class);
        Drawable mySelector = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_varaframsteg);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("tab2",mySelector).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);



        intent = new Intent(this, MyWalks.class);

        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("tab3",
        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_minapromenader)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);



        intent = new Intent(this, WalkInformations.class);

        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab4").setIndicator("tab4",
        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_information)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    }
}
```

Comment: (thanks waqas  but it still not working same problem as before unique namw for eache newTabSpec)

Comment: or perhaps try adding names in `setIndicator` too. see my updated answer

Comment: still not work by adding both unique value newTebspec and setIndicator . i feeling great problem . if you have any tutorials in which more than two to three tab with diffrenet icons change on click

Comment: zip your project, upload it somewhere and send me the link